# Evaluating a sum related to the Riemann zeta function

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, riemann-zeta

How do I evaluate the sum
$$\sum_{0 <\gamma \leq T} x^{i\gamma}, $$
where $\gamma$ is the imaginary part of a non-trivial zero of Riemann's zeta function and $x, T>0$?

My attempt is
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\sum_{0 <\gamma \leq T} x^{i\gamma} &=\sum_{0 <\gamma \leq T} (\cos(\gamma \log x)+i\sin(\gamma \log x)) = \int_{0}^{T} \cos(\gamma \log x)  \mathrm{d}N(t)+i\int_{0}^{T} \sin(\gamma \log x)  \mathrm{d}N(t),
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
where $N(t)=O(t\log t)$ is the number of non-trivial zeros between $0$ and $t$. By change of variables,
$$\int_{0}^{T} \cos(t \log x)  \mathrm{d}N(t)+i\int_{0}^{T} \sin(t\log x)  \mathrm{d}N(t)=\int_{0}^{T} \cos(t \log x)\log t  \mathrm{d}t+i\int_{0}^{T} \sin(t \log x) \log t \mathrm{d}t.$$
But the above integrals do not have a plain solution.

Comment: With enough manipulation, you might be able to find a complicated expression involving the Riemann zeta function, but you likely can't do better unless you have exact expressions for the imaginary parts of the zeros.

Comment: @AlannRosas What exact expressions? Were you figuring $\gamma_n \sim 2\pi n /\log n$, for the $n$-th zero $\gamma_n$?

Comment: @ksmfv I've never seen that estimate, so I can't say if its correct. Regardless, that's only an estimate of the imaginary parts, so it will only yield approximate expressions for your sum, not exact ones.

Comment: [This paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01203390) might be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

if RH is true one has for fixed $x>1$ and $T>T_x$ that $$\sum_{0 <\gamma \leq T} x^{i\gamma}=-\frac{T}{2\pi}\frac{\Lambda(x)}{\sqrt x}+\frac{x^{iT}\log (T/2x)}{2\pi i \log x}+O(\frac{\log T}{\log \log T})$$ while there is a formula more complicated that is universal in $x, T$ but the main term is still $-\frac{T}{2\pi}\frac{\Lambda(x)}{\sqrt x}$, where as usual $\Lambda(x)=\log p, x=p^n, n \ge 1$ and $0$ otherwise

See [Fujii, On A Theorem of Landau II](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/proceedings-of-the-japan-academy-series-a-mathematical-sciences/volume-66/issue-9/On-a-theorem-of-Landau-II/10.3792/pjaa.66.291.full)

Unconditionally one can estimate  $$\sum_{0 <\gamma \leq T} x^{\beta+i\gamma}=-\frac{T}{2\pi}\Lambda(x)+O(\log T)$$ again for $x>1$ fixed and $T>T_x$ and a more complicated expression that is universal in $(x,T)$ but now we cannot say much more about $$\sum_{0 <\gamma \leq T} x^{i\gamma}$$ since we may have lots of non trivial zeroes with $\beta \to 0$ for which the two sums (with $\beta+i\gamma$ and $i\gamma$ only) are similar

See [Fujii, On A Theorem of Landau I](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/proceedings-of-the-japan-academy-series-a-mathematical-sciences/volume-65/issue-2/On-a-theorem-of-Landau/10.3792/pjaa.65.51.full) and references there